# Texture(AsyncDisplayKit) image flash

Tags: swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have a viewcontroller inheriting `ASDKViewController`, the background is set to a picture, when I switch tabs, the picture flashes，how can i fix it?

[image]

in `SceneDelegate`:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    

    
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    
    let tab = UITabBarController()
    let vc1 = ViewController()
    vc1.title = "vc1"
    let vc2 = TestViewController()
    vc2.title = "vc2"
    tab.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2]
    window?.rootViewController = tab
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: ASDKViewController<ASDisplayNode> {

override init() {
    let bgImageView = ASImageNode()
    bgImageView.image = UIImage(named: "backBg")
    bgImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    super.init(node: bgImageView)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: I think its related with async call in .image property. White screen before image - is placehodlerColor. Maybe.

Comment: @Bimawa Yes, it is caused by asynchronous, but i still not find the solution. :(     
and placehodlerColor default is nil.

Comment: check the next properties: - displaysAsynchronously: should be false.

Comment: or create custom node  cross initWithViewBlock: method

Comment: @Bimawa set displaysAsynchronously to false  does work! thanks :)

Comment: ok, cool, check pls my answer. Correctly it or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the solution will be:

```
    let bgImageView = ASImageNode()
    bgImageView.displaysAsynchronously = false
```